# OnScreen event in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a small custom control which downloads & displays a contacts image. It ensures that only 1 image is being downloaded at a time by adding itself to a static queue of images awaiting to be downloaded.

It is possible to get quite long contact lists. So I want it to only enter the download queue when it actually becomes visible on the screen (there's a default image).

I've tried placing the logic in the `Loaded` event, overriding `OnRender` and the `IsVisibleChanged` event, but none seem to give me what I want.

any suggestions?

D.R

**Edit:**
This is a WPF Application, sorry for not mentioning before...

Comment: Where are you showing this control? If it's inside a ListBox, ListView, ItemsControl, etc., then you can use a virtualizing items control, and the item template won't be created until the item is scrolled into view. If it's inside something else, like a FlowDocument, you'll need to do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some system controls (like ListView) have property "VirtualMode" if you set it to true and handle RetrieveVirtualItem event. This event invokes for items which are visible currently and you have to fill those items with data(images) you want. So that you don't need to fill all items at once.

Comment: Sorry I should of specified more clearly then with tags that I'm working with WPF.

Comment: it doesn't metter. WPF controls also support Virtual mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [`PriorityBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) in order to provide that functionality?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="{StaticResource ImgDownloading}">
                    <Binding Path="ImageSource" IsAsync="True" />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I encapsulated the functionality in a custom control so that I would have more control over how the images are downloaded, i.e. If I searched for "a" and got 500 contact records back, surely the priority binding would try to download 500 images and not just the images that are currently visible on the screen?

Comment: You would have the `ImageSource` property access a blocking resource to download the images. That resource would handle one at a time loading.